# Javascript if statement inside of another if statement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to put an if statement inside of another if statement, and I think I did something very easy to fix, but I can't figure out what or where it is. I am stuck with this and any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

```
var player = 0;
var xvalue = 0;
var ovalue = 0;
function tic(a) 
{
    if(player === 0)
    {
        document.getElementById(a).value = 'X';
        document.getElementById(a).disabled = 'true';
        player = 1;
        if(a === 'aa')
        {
            var i = 1
            for(i = 1; i <= 1; i++; )
            {
                xvalue++;
            }
        }
        else if(a === 'ab')
        {
            var i = 1
            for(i = 1; i <= 2; i++; )
            {
                xvalue++;
            }
            else if(a === 'ac')
            {
                var i = 1
                for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++; )
                {
                    xvalue++;
                }
                else if(a === 'ba')
                {
                    var i = 1
                    for(i = 1; i <= 8; i++; )
                    {
                        xvalue++;
                    }
                    else if(a === 'bb')
                    {
                        var i = 1
                        for(i = 1; i <= 16; i++; )
                        {
                            xvalue++;
                        }
                        else if(a === 'bc')
                        {
                            var i = 1
                            for(i = 1; i <= 32; i++; )
                            {
                                xvalue++;
                            }
                            else if(a === 'ca')
                            {
                                var i = 1
                                for(i = 1; i <= 64; i++; )
                                {
                                    xvalue++;
                                }
                                else if(a === 'cb')
                                {
                                    var i = 1
                                    for(i = 1; i <= 128; i++; )
                                    {
                                        xvalue++;
                                    }
                                    else if(a === 'cc')
                                    {
                                        var i = 1
                                        for(i = 1; i <= 256; i++; )
                                        {
                                            xvalue++;
                                        }
                                        if(xvalue === 448)
                                        {
                                            alert("player 1 wins!");
                                        }
                                        else if(xvalue === 7)
                                        {
                                            alert("player 1 wins!");
                                        }
                                        else if(xvalue === 56)
                                        {
                                            alert("player 1 wins!");
                                        }
                                        else if(xvalue === 273)
                                        {
                                            alert("player 1 wins!");
                                        }
                                        else if(xvalue === 84)
                                        {
                                            alert("player 1 wins!");
                                        }
                                        else if(xvalue === 73)
                                        {
                                            alert("player 1 wins!");
                                        }
                                        else if(xvalue === 146)
                                        {
                                            alert("player 1 wins!");
                                        }
                                        else if(xvalue === 292)
                                        {
                                            alert("player 1 wins!");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        document.getElementById(a).value = 'O';
                                        document.getElementById(a).disabled = 'true';
                                        player = 0;
                                    }
                                }
```

Comment: I'm sorry. But don't really see what the question is?

Comment: ...aaaaand the problem is what exactly?

Comment: What is the console.log of a you are passing into the tic-function?

Comment: `for`s aren't terminated.

Comment: Same as @Marcell -- you are missing a bunch of closing braces in your blocks.

Comment: ...and that is why correct formatting is so important.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is riddled with syntax errors:

```
 else if(a === 'ab'){
        var i = 1
        for(i = 1; i <= 2; i++; ){
            xvalue++;
    }
```

You're opening the `else if` block, and inside, you open a `for` block, but only close one. It should've been:

```
 else if(a === 'ab'){
        var i = 1
        for(i = 1; i <= 2; i++; ){
            xvalue++;
        }//<-- close for loops
    }// then close else if block
```

To nest `if`'s is pretty easy, and you seem to be doing it right, but perhaps you were asking if it was possible to combine the outer & inner ifs. In that case: yes:

```
if (player === 0 && a === 'aaa')
```

Works perfectly fine, too.
But to be honest you really need to practice a bit more: JS global variables should be avoided: functions should be passed parameters.

Comment: Since all of the loops and if statements only have one line inside them, you can omit the curly brackets in most cases = less lines :)

Comment: @NicolaiDitlevKroghKrüger: That's all well and good, but OP is clearly still learning the basics. I'd say writing those braces is a good habit. Remember the `goto fail;` bug?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem First of all thank you, but when I tried your suggestion the console said that the function "tic" wasn't defined. Do you have an answer for that?

Comment: @user2059810: well, the error says it all: check your code for `function tic(){`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I already looked at that and I can't seem to find out what the issue is